# Blue Screen Of Death after Graphics Card Update

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, windows-8.1, bsod, amd-radeon

I recently installed the game watch dogs
After installing it i upgraded the drivers on my graphics card AMD Radion R9 200 series via the catalyst software and since then windows has been crashing on an ad-hoc basis even when sitting idle

I have recieved two different sets of errors OXOOOOOOO1 and VIDEO_SCHEDULER_INTERNAL_ERROR

I am running windows 8.1 with the driver 14.4 from AMD

My PC shouldnt really be having this problem as it is pretty high spec due to my work

Any help would be greatly appreciated as it is driving me up the walls a bit

**[UPDATE 08-06-2014]**

I have been looking around online and have crashed the PC a few times now trying to recreate the bug

I have looked into the event history viewer and gotten the following errors

**amdacpusrsvc
acpusrsvc: IOCTL_ACPKSD_KSD_TO_USR_SVC_SET_FB_APERTURES: FAILED**

**acpusrsvc: GfxMemServiceInitialize: FAILED**

**amdacpusrsvc
acpusrsvc: IOCTL_ACPKSD_KSD_TO_USR_SVC_SET_FB_APERTURES: FAILED**

**amdacpusrsvc
acpusrsvc: GfxMemServiceInitialize: FAILED**

I took some advice from the AMD forums to re-install the old drivers to see if they would work. I uninstalled the old ones first and installed directly from the CD

I got the warnings below but the driver installed "successfully"

The Warnings are
***amdacpusrsvc
acpusrsvc: ConfigureFrameBufferMemory: FAILED.***

Hopefully this will spark something off for someone

Thanks
John

Comment: What happens when you roll back the drivers to the older, working version?

Comment: 1. `windows has been crashing on an ad-hoc basis` - do you mean intermittent? I don't know what an ad-hoc crash is - 2. `My PC shouldnt really be having this problem as it is pretty high spec due to my work` - Drivers don't care about the specs of your machine or how much your machine cost. Even the most expensive, highest spec workstations and servers experience driver issues. - 3. Try rolling back the driver. If that resolves it then you could look for a driver that's more current than the one that's crashing or you could try a driver provided by the computer manufacturer.

Comment: Hi Guys thanks for the quick responses. The Graphics card in question is a 4096MB Asus Radeon R9 290X DirectCU II Aktiv PCIe 3.0 x16 2xDVI/1xHDMI/1xDisplayPort. The Driver which was automatically set up for it is 14.10.1006-140417a-171099C. Hi @ChrisInEdmonton, I have since reinstalled windows so i only have the current drivers.

Comment: @joeqwerty yes I mean on an intermittent basis.

Comment: Updating drivers for the graphics card can be a really cumbersome process especially if you're not a 100% sure that the driver you are installing was actually made for your hardware, which is why I suggest you use [Raptr](http://raptr.com/amd) since you have an AMD GPU. It should automatically download the latest graphics driver for your card so you don't have to.

Comment: Hi @Vinayak I had that before and used it to update the drivers. I wasnt sure if it wasnt responsible for causing the problem in the first place. Just to confirm Asus is the same company as AMD?

Comment: Asus is not AMD. Asus makes computers (notebooks, desktops, smartphones and the like). AMD makes processors and graphics cards. "Gaming Evolved" however (the name of the software program) is AMD's answer to Nvidia's "GeForce Experience" and does the same things that GeForce Experience does (updates Nvidia graphics drivers, downloads optimized graphics settings for games based on the GPU you use) but for AMD GPUs.

Comment: So the fact that i have a Asus Radeon R9 290X and have installed drivers for an AMD Radeon R9 200 Series shouldnt be the reason for the PC crashing? I just want to eliminate the obvious so we can start delving into the stuff outside my pay grade :)

Comment: Hi @justcool393 I have looked at the previous four dumps and they say that the following processes is at fault for the failures:ntoskrnl.exe

Comment: @justcool393 Im not sure how to attach but please find it here [link](http://1drv.ms/TvS9eL). Its a link to skydrive

Comment: @justcool393 I have added a couple of more dumps if you think it will be useful [link](http://1drv.ms/1mt8hEG)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crash dumps were inconclusive (not your fault, but the driver corrupted the stack), looking at the drivers loaded at the time, and previous crashes by other people, it looks to have something to do with the CCC driver (*atikmdag.sys*).

The Catalyst Control Center is probably causing the issue (it looks to be the only thing causing 0xA0000001 blue screens. Have you tried updating the control center? If that doesn't seem to fix it, try re-installing it.

Comment: I have tried updating it to the latest version, I reistalled windows, I uninstalled the drivers, I tried older versions of the driver, nothing seems to improve it. Do you think I should try installing microsofts verson. The forums on AMD  have suggested the RAM in the GPU may be physically broken. I will try anything even downgrade to wimdows seven at this stage. I am out of ideas but appreciate you taking the time to have a look at the memory dumps

Comment: It isnt possible because windows update has detected the previously installed version even when I removed it and ran ccleaner on it and throws an error. I will try format the drive tomorrow and freshly install windows eight again. If that fails il email AMD and the company I bought the card off and ask if they have any ideas or another card. Its still under warrenty but its a hassle. Thanks for helping me